# Beautiful soup gives output as "Searching for your content..." when trying to get main article text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the main article text from some pages on newswire website using beautiful soup. But instead of the text output. I get an output that says "Searching for your content..."

I would highly appreciate any help. I seem to be doing something fundamentally wrong here. (I'm sorry about that, if I'm doing it the wrong way as I'm a beginner in coding)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

site= "https://www.newswire.ca/news-releases/rbc-capital-markets-launches-aiden-r-a-new-ai-powered-electronic-trading-platform-891623791.html"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

text = soup.find_all('p', {"class":"text-muted"})[0].text.strip()
print(text)
```

Comment: Data is dynamic generated in `p` tags from ::before in html so try out selenium or find endpoint from xhr if you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CSS selector `".release-body"`:

```py
from textwrap import wrap
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

site = "https://www.newswire.ca/news-releases/rbc-capital-markets-launches-aiden-r-a-new-ai-powered-electronic-trading-platform-891623791.html"
hdr = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
text = soup.select_one(".release-body").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")

print("\n".join(wrap(text, width=80)))
```

Prints:

```
Traders and AI scientists at RBC and Borealis AI collaborate to deliver a real-
world AI solution to help improve trading results and insights for clients in a
measurable and explainable way NEW YORK , Oct. 14, 2020 /CNW/ - RBC Capital
Markets today announced the launch of Aiden ® , an AI-based electronic trading
platform that uses the computational power of deep reinforcement learning in its
pursuit of improved trading results and insights for clients. The Aiden ®
platform was developed jointly by RBC Capital Markets and Borealis AI, a world-
class AI research center created by RBC, as traders and AI scientists worked
side-by-side to create the initial bold concept and deliver a real-world
solution. In doing so, both organizations undertook one of the biggest
challenges in the field of AI today – applying deep reinforcement learning into
a constantly changing environment like equities trading, with measurable and
explainable results for its users. "Aiden ® speaks to our long-term commitment
to leverage next-generation AI technology to create differentiated solutions for
our clients," Bobby Grubert , Co-Head of Global Equities‎, RBC Capital Markets,
said. "Aiden ® is the result of a massive collaborative effort between RBC

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Andrej. That works like a charm!!! And this way is much faster and efficient compared to using selenium (which was my last hope). Really appreciate your help!!!